# How to access directories disallowed in robots.txt?

Tags: php, apache, vulnerability

While scanning my website with uniscan it found my `robots.txt` file which disallows access to `/cgi-bin/` and other directories, but they are not accessible in browser. Is there a way to access the directories or files which are Disallowed?

Comment: I hope you have other restrictions on cgi-bin - like .htaccess rules and suitable permissions set on the files in that folder.

Comment: Also, your robots.txt file can contain entries that don't really exist so you might think security is stopping you from reading a url that really just isn't there.

Comment: "but they are not accessible in browser" - If they are not accessible then either they don't exist, or there is something else that is blocking them. "robots.txt" is only an advisory document for good bots.

Comment: `robots.txt` is not a security feature, it's not even a set of rules, it's just a "suggestion" really

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The robots.txt does not disallow you to access directories. It tells Google and Bing not to index certain folders. If you put secret folders in there, Google and Bing will ignore them, but other malicious scanners will probably do the opposite. In effect you're giving away what you want to keep secret. To disallow folders you should set this in Apache vhost or .htaccess. You can set a login on the folder if you want.

Comment: As a side note; It is possible to build a trap page in robots.txt, to stop bad crawlers. Ref.: http://www.bsdguides.org/2012/a-simple-bot-trap-using-robots-txt/ - But this is not effective against humans, as they can comprehend that they triggered a trap, and continue the list with a new ip-address.

Comment: Nice tip, especially the fail2ban trick!

Comment: "not to index certain folders" - actually, it tells the good bots _not to **crawl** certain files and folders_. Disallowed pages can still be indexed (link only), particularly if other pages are linking to them.

Comment: I wonder how this works. You could put a page inside such a folder with its own robot metatag to allow indexing, and I can imagine that has precedence. But I guess that if I link to a page in a folder with a disallow-index setting, that page should not be indexed. Google should follow the robots.txt guide, and the only exception should be a metatag in the page itself.

Answer (score 10):

The robots.txt file isn't a security measure and has no incidence on access permission.
This file only tells 'good' robots to skip a part of your website to avoid indexation. Bad robots don't even abide by those rules and scan all they can find. So security can never rely on the robots.txt file (that's not its purpose).

> Is there a way to access the directories or files which are
>   Disallowed?

Check your webserver's permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just go to the directory.

`robots.txt` is nothing more than something a crawler follows out of courtesy. Crawlers are free to entirely ignore the file. It isn't a real method to keep directories private.